# Why R repeats logical indexes?

Tags: r

I have noticed a curious quirk in R.  Let's say I have a vector and I want to use `logical` indices where I intend to just refer to the first two elements.

```
vec <- rep(2, 10)
vec[c(TRUE,FALSE)] <- 13
```

My output now shows `13` assigned in every other value

```
vec
[1] 13  2 13  2 13  2 13  2 13  2
```

Now, I know I could just use the `numeric` indices (for example wrapping the `logical` values with a `which` call) but I am curious about this.

**Why does R repeat `logical` values when indexing a vector?**

Comment: Why would you constrain the recycling rule to particular types?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule

Comment: It's because length doesn't match in between c(T,F) and  rep(2,10) so it's repeated 5 times. All Trues get 13 as override

Comment: Ah, the 'recycling rule'.  That is what I was looking for.  Thank you.